# INFORMIX: UPDATE with ALIAS?

Tags: sql, alias, informix

```
update prpcopycoins a set a.comtype=(
    select b.comtype from prpcopycoins b where b.policyno=a.policyno and b.serialno=a.serialno and b.applyno[1]='E')
where a.applyno in ('1461F00001', '1461F00002');
```

I'm trying to update several rows of table `prpcopycoins` with values from other rows of the same table. The above code got a syntax error because of the alias represented. How to correct it?

I'm using 'IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC8W4'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing `UPDATE` documentation from Informix [11.50](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm) and [11.70](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm) I see that aliasing can be used in 11.70 and is not available in 11.50. I also have 11.50 and I cannot use aliases in `UPDATE`.

I would write SPL function `getcomtype(policyno, serialno)` and use it like:

```
update prpcopycoins set comtype=getcomtype(policyno, serialno)
where applyno in ('1461F00001', '1461F00002');
```